Are OEM spark plugs superior to aftermarket?
In general, is it a good idea to go with OEM spark plugs or is it one of those parts where aftermarket can be just as good (or even better)?
Not necessarily talking about performance or motorsports or whatever, just daily driving.

Spark plugs, in general, are much better than they were 50 years ago (although going to fuel injection vs carburetor is responsible for at least some of that). Can't remember the last time I saw a spark plug commercial on TV.

Basically, spark plug manufacture and type is not going to matter as far as power in the engine goes. A couple of different videos proving this are:

https://youtu.be/Ft6YOBjd5FE?si=3uFUHw3GCwraX1bj
https://youtu.be/X31bCPiwaIk?si=NXKLocZVQJ0jo9x3

You will want to get the type of plug (ie: copper; platinum; iridium; etc) which the manufacturer specifies for your vehicle. This is because each different type lasts differently. You'll want to use the right type so that they will wear as expected.

As far as I know, car manufacturers don’t make their own spark plugs.  They will all use spark plugs from the high end manufacturers like NGK, Bosch, Champion etc.  For a standard performance engine, a spark plug with the correct specification from any of the well known brands should be fine.
